# Plot only certain data in plotly express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

With plotly express, how do you plot only a specified subset of the dataframe when it is formatted as long? With a wide dataframe, I know I can use the "y" parameter to specify a list of columns, but I'm not sure how to do something similar for a long dataframe.

The only way I know to do this for a long dataframe is to make a copy of the dataframe with only the desired data, but I'm wondering if there's another way.

Here's an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# get data for countries in Europe
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Europe'")


# plot population for all countries
fig1 = px.line(df, x='year', y='pop', color='country',
                title="All Available Countries in Europe")
fig1.show()


# plot population for some countries

# first make a new dataframe with selected data
countries = ['France', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Germany', ]
newdf = df[df['country'].isin(countries)]

# then plot new dataframe
fig2 = px.line(newdf, x='year', y='pop', color='country',
                title="Some Countries in Europe")
fig2.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the DataFrame filter directly in the plot command, e.g.

```
fig2 = px.line(df[df['country'].isin(countries)], x='year', y='pop', color='country')
fig2.show()
```

This is the same thing as creating a separate DataFrame, except that the GarbageCollector / namespace doesn't try to hold onto the result, so you save a bit of memory and time if you're doing this over and over with slightly different filters.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a feature of the line function that could do it without having to pass a modified DataFrame, but perhaps not.